# Selenium - Callback not provided in execute_async_script

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have the following code that should wait 2 seconds while this async Javascript executes, and then call the callback. But, for some reason, `arguments[0]` is not a callback even though the Selenium documentation I have found states that with `execute_async_script` a callback function is automatically injected into the `arguments` array.

```
driver.execute_async_script(f"""
    function sleep(ms) {{
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }}
    async function test() {{
        console.log("before 2")
        await sleep(2000)
        console.log("after 2")
        console.log(arguments)
        arguments[0]()
    }}
    test()
    """)
```

`arguments` is logged as an empty array.

What is going on?

Selenium documentation: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebDriver.html#executeAsyncScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the callback at the start of the executed Javascript, like this:

```
driver.execute_async_script(f"""
const cb = arguments[arguments.length - 1]
function sleep(ms) {{
return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}}
async function test() {{
    console.log("before 2")
    await sleep(2000)
    console.log("after 2")
    console.log(arguments)
    cb()
}}
test()
""")
```

This makes sense because `arguments` is an object that changes depending upon the function it is accessed it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments